# ember js : if equals issue with params

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to compare 2 values in ember js. Below is the implementation of the solution which I found on the stack overflow.com

Template

```
{{#if sectionfeedIsEqual param1=section.id param2=sectionfeed.sectionDefinitionID}}
                                    {{section.id}} is equal to {{sectionfeed.sectionDefinitionID}}
{{/if}}
```

Controller

```
sectionfeedIsEqual: (function() {
    {{debugger}}
    return this.get('param1') === this.get('param2'); <- undefined inthis.get('param1')
}.property('param1', 'param2')
)
```

I don't get values in this.get('param1') or this.get('param2')

Comment: Where was this SO solution you supposedly found? Read the documentation on `{{#if}}`. You give it a single boolean value, nothing more. If you want something more complicated, in general you need to pre-compute it as a property on the view/controller/model.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't set controller properties from `{{#if}}` helper (see [my JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/losuqewoqo/1/edit)). So for sure you're getting `undefined` because these properties weren't defined in controller. For this case you should either write custom helper (like [this](http://doginthehat.com.au/2012/02/comparison-block-helper-for-handlebars-templates/)) or change `sectionfeedIsEqual` definition:

```
sectionfeedIsEqual: (function() {
    return this.get('section.id') === this.get('sectionfeed.sectionDefinitionID');
}.property('section.id', 'sectionfeed.sectionDefinitionID')
```

Comment: Thanks but that won't work, I am getting  Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must pass exactly one argument to the if helper

Comment: Well, that's because, ummm, you must pass exactly one argument to the if helper, but hey, wait a minute, that's exactly what the error message said, maybe you should actually read it and think about what it means. In other words, after doing the above you need to remove the cruft after the variable in the `{{#if}}` statement.